# Django {{ c }} not rendering

Tags: django-templates

Problem is that i can't get value to my template.

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.httpimport HttpResponse


def index(request):
 c='hi'
 return render_to_response('list.html', c)
```

list.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
 list{{ c }}
{% endblock %}
```

It renders `list` but not`{{ c }}` what could cause this? And it gives no error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render_to_response` expects its [context to be a dictionary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response), whereas you are passing your string directly:

```
def index(request):
    context = { 'c': 'hi' }
    return render_to_response('list.html', context)
```

Based on your comment below, if you want 'c' to be a list of things, it would look something like this instead:

```
def index(request):
    context = { 'c': ['hello', 'world'] }
    return render_to_response('list.html', context)
```

The basic idea is that you're building a mapping of the variables you want to reference in your template.  The names that you reference in the template are *keys* in the dictionary.

Comment: `{%for entry in c%}
list {{ entry }}
{%endfor%}` and making `c={'tere':'hi'}` didn't return anything
It renders the list.html, but not the values... and no error..

Comment: Your comment doesn't align with what you're asking in the question, but it seems you may be confused about what a dictionary is.  Your template is expecting a dictionary with names mapped to values.  If you're referencing a variable 'c' in your template, then your context dictionary must have an item with 'c' as the key { 'c':  <some value> }. What that value is can be anything, the important thing is that it's keyed by the name 'c' in the mapping.